# jQuery Validator depends method undefined

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Firebug is showing me the following:

[image: firebug screenshot]

From the followin Validator initialization:

```
$("#surveyForm").validate({
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) { 
    if ( element.is(":radio") ) {
        error.appendTo ( '#' + element.attr('name') + '_multiError' ); 
        } else if ( element.is(":checkbox") ) {
        error.appendTo ( '#' + element.attr('name') + '_multiError' );
        } else {
        error.appendTo( element.parent() );
        }
},
    rules: {
     ans_23: {
         depends: function(element) {
           return $("#ans_22:checked")
         }
 }
   },
   debug: true
});
```

The rule is based on the second example under rules [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options).

The HTML being referenced looks like this

```
<td class='two_columns'>
<label>
<input type='radio' name='rad_22' id='ans_22' class='required' value='Yes'  />  Other
</label>
<input type='text' name='ans_23' id='ans_23' value='' class='' />
</td>
```

Anyone know why the depends method would be undefined?

Footnote:  I also tried doing this using the rule add method (see below).  That form validated and threw no errors when validate() was called and ans_23 did not gain "required" class....

```
$("#surveyForm").rules("add", {
  ans_23: {
    required: "#ans_22:checked"
  }
});
```

Comment: `return $("#ans_22:checked")` needs to be `return $("#ans_22:checked").length`.

Comment: @alex - thanks.  I have added but still am getting "exception occured when checking element ans_23, check the 'depends' method TypeError: $.validator.methods[method] is undefined" from FireBug.

Comment: Make a http://jsfiddle.net and I can help you :)

Comment: Looks like you might be missing a level... 'depends' should be inside 'required' - see this SO post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975778/jquery-validate-depend-field

Comment: @alex - thanks! here's two:  http://jsfiddle.net/pbSPn/   http://jsfiddle.net/AVG86/2/

Comment: @mudfalcon - Thanks!  That solves it when specifying in rules()!  Add here as an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I saw a comment reply from you to convert my comment to an answer... so here goes:

```
$("#surveyForm").validate({
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) { 
    if ( element.is(":radio") ) {
        error.appendTo ( '#' + element.attr('name') + '_multiError' ); 
        } else if ( element.is(":checkbox") ) {
        error.appendTo ( '#' + element.attr('name') + '_multiError' );
        } else {
        error.appendTo( element.parent() );
        }
},
    rules: {
     ans_23: {
         required: {
           depends: function(element) {
             return $("#ans_22:checked");
           }
         }
 }
   },
   debug: true
});
```

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to be able to upvote you and credit the answer- thanks very much for the help!  My day was much improved by having this resolved!

Comment: This worked but I had to change `return $("#ans_22:checked");` to `return $("#ans_22:checked").length;`