# jquery validation plugin using conditons

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

i am using validation plugin to validate a form, here are my rules

```
$("#creatProfileForm").validate({
    ignore: [], //use for hidden fields validation, by default hidden fields are ignored
    rules : {
        "firstName" : {
            required : true,
        },
        "lastName" : {
            required : true,
        },
        "gender" : {
            required : true,
        },
        "password" : {
            required : function(element) {
                if($("#isSocialSignup").val() == "true" || $("#isSocialSignup").val() == true)
                    return true;
            },
            minLength : 6
        }
    },
        messages : {
            "firstName" : {
                required : 'First Name is required',
            },
            "lastName" : {
                required: "Last Name is required",
            },
            "gender" : {
                required : "Gender is required",
            },
            "password" : {
                required : "Password is required",
                minLength : "Lenght should be atleast 6 characters"
            }
        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) { //custom location for error placement
            if (element.attr("name") == "gender") {
              error.insertAfter(".temp");
            } else {
              error.insertAfter(element);
            }
          } 
});
```

UPDATE : if i remove the call back function and add "required:true", it works.

My problem is with password field, I have stored a Boolean value in view and using that value i am deciding the required for password field. If value is true, password is required else not required.

When i submit the form, on console i get "false" printed , but still password field also show message, `"password is required"`

What is wrong with my code. Kindly help me.
thanks in advance

Comment: Also show the HTML markup for this form.

Comment: You've spelled your `minlength` rule incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is simply that there is no such method as `minLength`.  You probably meant `minlength`.  As @rubyist suggested, you need to change your required dependency to this:

```
required: $("#isSocialSignup").val() == 'true' ? true : false,
```

The one you had with `$('#isSocialSignup').val() == 'true' || $('#isSocialSignup').val() == true`, the 2nd part of that where you compare to the boolean `true`, well `.val()` will always tell you that it's `true` if there's anything in it at all, including the word `"false"`.  So that probably wasn't helping you!

Beyond that, your code looks fine to me.  Too many trailing commas, which will upset IE users:

```
"gender": {
   required: true, //<---- that comma will cause an issue
}, //<--- this one won't because there is something after it
```

Semi-similar working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/D59ZW/

Comment: +1... I didn't notice that you already caught the `minLength` error when I posted my answer.  I too believe that this is the root cause of the whole problem.  [The trailing commas are pretty sloppy coding but the IE version has to be pretty old (6 & 7) for this to be a real problem](http://trailingcomma.com/).

Comment: From my experience, IE6/7 is still sadly prevalent, especially in corporate environments.  I've happily stopped trying to make things pretty in IE6/7, but it is still nice for everything to at least work!

Comment: That's very true, however I think it's worthwhile to point out this won't affect the _majority_ of "IE users".

Comment: @Ryley thankyou so much, it works, problem was with "L". when i changed it to "minlength" , it worked.

Answer (score 1):

**Quote OP's comments**:

> *"...error in firebug console `$.validate.method[method] is undefined`"*

and

> *"...with `required:false`, it gives the same error (`$.validate.method[method] is undefined`) and submits the form."*

The problem is simple... there is no such method called `minLength`.

The method is called `minlength` => note the lower-case `l` in place of the upper-case `L`.

See:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/minlength-method/

Comment: thank you so much for you time and help. I marked Ryley's answer as i saw that first. Thank you once again for help and time.

Answer (score 0):

Use the depends option: http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/

```
required: {
            depends: function(element) {
                return $("#isSocialSignup").val() == "true" || $("#isSocialSignup").val() == true
            }
        }
```

Comment: my form gets submit and show the following error in firebug console "$.validate.method[method] is undefined"

Comment: The `depends` option is not mandatory.  A proper function in place of the `value` will also work when declaring the rule.  See:  http://jsfiddle.net/LzRDB/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
rules : {
            "firstName" : {
                required : true,
            },
            "lastName" : {
                required : true,
            },
            "gender" : {
                required : true,
            },
            "password" : {
                required: $("#isSocialSignup").val() == 'true' ? true : false,
                minLength : 6
            }
        },
```

Comment: my form gets submit and show the following error in firebug console "$.validate.method[method] is undefined"

Comment: I think you are passing string as a params and string does not have val() method.....just check again

Comment: console.debug($("#isSocialSignup").val()), this statement prints "false" on console

Comment: try this $("#isSocialSignup").val() == 'true' ? true : false

Comment: i tried it and gives error on console, i thing "required:false" is creating some problem.

Comment: see here..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9026740/jquery-validator-depends-method-undefined

Comment: if you are just doing required: false then it's also working right?

Comment: No, with required:false, it gives the same error ($.validate.method[method] is undefined) and submits the form.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
  debug: true,
  success: "valid"
  });
$("#creatProfileForm").validate({
    rules : {
        "firstName" : {
            required : true,
        },
        "lastName" : {
            required : true,
        },
        "gender" : {
            required : true,
        },
        "password" : {
            required: ($("#isSocialSignup").val() == "true" || $("#isSocialSignup").val() == true) ? true : false,
            minLength : 6
        }
    },
        messages : {
            "firstName" : {
                required : 'First Name is required',
            },
            "lastName" : {
                required: "Last Name is required",
            },
            "gender" : {
                required : "Gender is required",
            },
            "password" : {
                required : "Password is required",
                minLength : "Lenght should be atleast 6 characters"
            }
        },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
    form.submit();
    }
});
```