# jQuery Validate Plugin: how to validate a dropdown

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-validate

I'm trying to use the jQuery Validate plugin to validate a dropdown.  It validates the rest of my form correctly.  But it doesn't work on the dropdown.

Here is my jQuery:

```
$('#campaignForm').validate({
    rules: {
         campaign_name: {
             required: true
         },
         html_url: {
             required: {
                 depends: function(element) {
                     return $('#html_url').val() == 'none';
                 }
              }
         }
    },
    messages: {
        campaign_name: 'Please enter a campaign name',
        html_url: 'Please select a template'
    }
});
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<select name="html_url" id="html_url">
<option value="none">Select One...</option>
...
</select>
```

What am I doing wrong?  Are my variable names colliding somehow.  The rule for campaign name works fine.

Comment: I've tried both and I don't get a message for either.  Could it be validating correctly and the message just isn't showing?  If so, how do I get it to show?

Comment: This may be part of the problem, actually: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9890284/139010

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking because your usage of the `depends:` option is somewhat misleading.  If you just want to make a `select` `required`, you do not use `depends:` because it does not "depend" on another element...  see my answer.

Comment: Your `depends` property is only toggling the `required` rule.  However, the `required` rule will not work when all options already contain a `value`, since `required` will always be satisfied.

Answer (score 10):

If you just want to make a `select` element `required`, you would not use `depends:` because it does not "depend" on *another element*.  In your usage, the `depends` property is simply toggling the `required` rule.  The problem here is not the `required` rule... it does not need to be toggled.  The problem is that the `required` rule will not work when all options already contain a `value`, since `required` will always be satisfied.

Simply use `value=""` for the default option, and then set your rules just like any other element.

```
<option value="">Select One...</option>
```

[**jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/bgwmN/1/)

**HTML:**

```
<form id="campaignForm">   
    <select name="html_url" id="html_url">  
        <option value="">Select One...</option>
        <option value="one">ONE</option>
        <option value="two">TWO</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>​
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#campaignForm').validate({
        rules: {
            html_url: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            html_url: {
                required: 'Please select a template'
            }
        }
    });
});​
```

Comment: why to use `value=""` ?  why `depend: "required"` is not work?

Comment: @Prashant, because if the `value` is not set to blank, then how would the plugin know that no selection has been made?  `value=""` is the selection that tells the plugin ***no selection*** has yet been made.   The `depends` property is only toggling the `required` rule.  However, the `required` rule will not work when all options already contain a `value`, since `required` will always be satisfied.

Answer (score 5):

If for some reason you can't set the value to blank like Spark said, you can just add your own JQuery validation function instead of the default required preset.

```
$.validator.addMethod("aFunction",
    function(value, element) {
        if (value == "none")
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    },
    "Please select a value");

$('#campaignForm').validate({
    rules: {
         campaign_name: {
             required: true
         },
         html_url: {
             aFunction: true
         }
    },
    messages: {
        campaign_name: 'Please enter a campaign name',
        html_url: 'Please select a template'
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#campaignForm').validate({
    rules: {
        html_url: {
            min: 1,
        }
    },
    messages: {
        html_url: 'Please select a template',
    }
});
```