# Form validate with If

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have to validate a form like this:

```
$('#formfile').validate({
    highlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
    },
    unhighlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
    },
    ignore: '',
    //focusInvalid: true,
    errorElement: 'span',
    errorClass: 'help-block',
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        if(element.parent('.input-group').length) {
            error.insertAfter(element.parent());
        } else {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
        element.focus();
    },
    rules: {
        if(country == "INDONESIA") {
            tax: {
                required: true              
            }
        }
    },
    messages: {
        if(country == "INDONESIA") {
            tax: "Please insert file Tax"
        }
    }
});
```

Can I do that? I want to check if `Country` is Indonesia or not, and if `Country` is Indonesia that field must be mandatory. Otherwise, if `Country` is not Indonesia, that field can be ignored. Any suggestion?

Edit: I forgot I used variable to get Country - `var Country = $('#country').val();`

Comment: with your code as is written, do you see errors in the developer tools console? (the answer is, you do see errors)

Comment: is said "==" not a function

Comment: Title does not represent the question **at all**. change it

Answer (score 0):

Try this ;)

You could use `depends`:

```
...
    rules: {
        tax: {
            required: {
                depends: function(element) {
                    return ($('#country').val() == 'INDONESIA');
                }
            }
        }
    }
...
```

[Jquery validate depend field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975778/jquery-validate-depend-field)

Comment: What is not working are you getting any error check console for errors; and update question with latest code you are using;

Comment: there's nothing happening or warning. Tax must be fileld.

Comment: It would be easy to debug things if you can create a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/);

Answer (score 0):

You could use the inline conditional operator to do it:

```
        rules: {
            country=="INDONESIA" ? 
              {
                  tax: {
                      required: true              
                  }
              } 
              : { }
```